# Reindexing a series returns NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series, multi-index, reindex

The following code returns a series with NaNs everywhere:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["c", "d", "e"]]))

s.reindex([('E', 'g'), ('E', 'h'), ('E', 'i'), ('F', 'g'), ('F', 'h'), ('F', 'i')])
```

or

```
s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['E', 'F'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]))
```

How can I reindex the series and retain the original values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not `reindex` , that is change the `index`

```
s.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['E', 'F'], ['g', 'h', 'i']])
s
Out[362]: 
E  g    1
   h    2
   i    3
F  g    4
   h    5
   i    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yeah, "reindex" means "look up these values," not "replace the index."

Answer (score 1):

If need set new values to second level use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
s.index = s.index.set_levels(['g', 'h', 'i'], level=1)
print (s)
A  g    1
   h    2
   i    3
B  g    4
   h    5
   i    6
dtype: int64
```